# Imagemagick label font size/background

Tags: background, imagemagick, label, font-size, fill

I can't seem to control font size, background and fill.

command 1:

```
convert             \
   testimage.jpg    \
   label:'Days: 0'  \
  -background Black \
  -fill White       \
  -pointsize 1      \
  -gravity center   \
  -append           \
   days_1.jpg
```

image:

[image]

command 2:

```
convert             \
   testimage.jpg    \
   label:'Days: 0'  \
  -background White \
  -fill Black       \
  -pointsize 48     \
  -gravity center   \
  -append           \
   days_2.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't do it right  :-)

You seem to misunderstand the meaning of `-label`.

See what the official docu has to say about `-label`:

> *A label is not drawn on the image, but is embedded in the image datastream via Label tag or similar mechanism. If you want the label to be visible on the image itself, use the -draw option...*

Try this command:

```
convert                               \
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoTPN.jpg \
  -pointsize 48                       \
  -fill green                         \
  -gravity center                     \
  -draw "text 100,-200 'Day: 0'"      \
   so-12359743-labelled.png
```

and you should get this result:

[image: resulting image]

Remember these rules when using `-draw`:

> You can set the primitive color, font, and font bounding box color with **`-fill`**, **`-font`**, and **`-box`** respectively. *Options are processed in command line order* so be sure to use these options **before** the **`-draw`** option.

(my emphasis)

Alternatively to `-draw` you can also use `-annotate` to put text into an image. (However, `-annotate` uses a slightly different syntax, which you can easily read up about.)

---

**Update**

Why didn't you take my hint about the order of the options?!?

Try this command:

```
convert                               \
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Exm.jpg \
  -background White                   \
  -fill Black                         \
  -pointsize 48                       \
  -gravity center                     \
   label:'Days: 0'                    \
  -append                             \
   days_2.jpg
```

and you'll get:

[image: result with '-append']

Remember, your `-append` does concatenate 2 different images:

1. The first one is your original input image.
2. The second one is freshly created with `-background ... -fill ... -pointsize ... -label ...`.

Concatenation with `-append` does not support `-gravity center`. This option would only make sense if you had also defined a canvas size for your second picture with `-size`, but you haven't.

In the absence of a pre-defined canvas size, the `-label` operation will auto-create one that is just big enough to hold the text string. You can verify this behavior with this command:

```
convert                               \
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Exm.jpg \
  -background White                   \
  -fill Black                         \
  -pointsize 48                       \
  -gravity center                     \
   label:'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' \
  -append                             \
   days_3.jpg
```

Your attempt to use `-gravity center` led me to believe you wanted the text to appear somewhere in the middle of the original input image. Hence my pointing to `-draw` and `-annotate`.

Comment: But I was just using the first example here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#anno_below

Actually, farther down that page is the comment:  "The "-draw" operator is no longer recommended for direct drawing onto images, unless part of more complex drawing functions. See the section on Text to Image Handling for more details of other text drawing methods and techniques."

Based on a later example, the following is working:

montage -label "hello there"  SkinMattekNutrient_py_14270.png  -pointsize 12 -gravity Center -fill Black -background White labeled3.jpg

Comment: @abalter: Text drawing isn't one of the "more complex drawing functions"!

Comment: Actually, the example you followed didn't use `-pointsize`. See also my update to the answer.

Comment: Worked awesomely!  Thanks.  Just curious: why does the order of operations matter?  I didn't see anything about that in the docs.  Based on your example, I got it to work using exactly the same command as I stated in the question, but just using the order of options you used.